# How do I tell if a laptop has a TPM without buying it first

Tags: tpm

With [TrueCrypt not officially supporting Windows 8 yet](http://www.truecrypt.org/future), Bitlocker appears to be the default option for full disk encryption on a new laptop.  However, Bitlocker suffers a major usability degradation on systems without a TPM (need to store keys on a flashdrive or enter a 48 digit pin instead of a password).

My problem is that I can't find any way to determine if a laptop is equipped with a TPM; even looking at models that I know have them (eg Dell Latitude) it doesn't appear to be listed anywhere.

Comment: There's always contacting the retailer and asking them straight out...

Comment: @Darael only as a last resort; and I'd probably be forced to contact OEMs directly since I'm skeptical about Newegg's support staff knowing that.

Comment: Quite.  It's far from optimal.  However, it's quite likely to be the only option in most cases.

Comment: I have noticed laptop brands also list it as feature on their websites

Comment: If you've came here in regards to Windows 11 upgrade requirements, I suggest looking at this question instead:  https://superuser.com/questions/1659465/will-my-computer-run-windows-11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least every system branded with [Intel vPro](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/vpro/vpro-technology-general.html) has to be equipped with a TPM.

For a particular model the manual usually states whether it has a TPM or not, at least the ones I checked. Sometimes they refer to the TPM as *security chip* or something like that, but when you search the documents you can usually find the terms *TPM* or *Trusted Platform Module*. Lenovo for example has a special section on BitLocker in the ThinkPad manuals I've had a look at.

As a rule of thumb, all business class systems come with a TPM (Lenovo ThinkPads, HP Elitebook, ...)

Comment: Some motherboards have them also.  Example: http://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/44/tech_080818_ultratpm.htm

Answer (score 0):

it *appears* that all 7th gen i-series intel processors have a tpm. but I've been so jaded about all this bullshit I'm not sure i fully trust that. dealing with tpm/bitlocker issues has made my life effin' miserable

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/7th-gen-core-family-desktop-brief.pdf