# Windows 11 update check cached?

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

Tried to get upgrade for Windows 11 - the Windows Update shows the PC does not meet requirements and the Microsoft PC Health Check shows it does (I have Asus ROG Strix X570-E with AMD Ryzen 9):

One explanation could be that I had TPM turned off and turned it on yesterday evening and the Windows Update is caching it somewhere. Otherwise there is a bug and Windows Update isnt recognising my system.

Anyone had this? Any idea how to solve it?

[image: Conventional way to upgrade]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 11 upgrade using ISO - INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE](https://superuser.com/questions/1680050/windows-11-upgrade-using-iso-inaccessible-boot-device)

Comment: TPM has to be version 2. older versions (1.2) are non compatible>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1659465/will-my-computer-run-windows-11

Comment: The Health Check checks for TPM. thank you for reading the question.. Not.

Comment: Have the exact same issue and scenario, as do some other people. I even used WhyNotWin11.exe which is supposed to be more detailed, and it says all good - unlike Windows Update. My guess is they'll fix it at some point, I heard they still have some performance issues with AMD anyway.

Comment: Update: The issue got resolved on my PC without additional action (other than perhaps an update and a logout-login).

Comment: I tried that few times too but it was no go.. so next day I gave up and installed it afresh (instead of upgrade)

Comment: Not only did I have the same question, but I had my windows arranged similarly as to take the same screenshot.