# Is there a way to upgrade to Windows 11 using USB?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I cant for some reason get Windows 11 upgrade through Windows Update (see here: [Windows 11 update check cached?](https://superuser.com/questions/1680043/windows-11-update-check-cached))

I downloaded Windows 11 ISO and "burnt" it to USB. If I boot from it - it starts fresh install of Windows 11 which I dont want.

When I tried to run `setup.exe` from the USB in Windows 10 hoping to upgrade - it throws the error below.

If I mount the ISO without USB and run `setup.exe` - it works fine (but cant finish the upgrade, see here: [Windows 11 upgrade using ISO - INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE](https://superuser.com/questions/1680050/windows-11-upgrade-using-iso-inaccessible-boot-device))

Is the USB install supposed to work as upgrade at all? Or is it only for fresh install?

[image]

Comment: Was your old system set up with CSM enabled and secure boot disabled? If you are now booting with CSM disabled then your old boot disk will no longer be "valid" to install on, hence an upgrade is not being offered.

Comment: I updated question here with bios info: https://superuser.com/questions/1680050/windows-11-upgrade-using-iso-inaccessible-boot-device - CSM is disabled and secure boot = User (dont know what that means). I have not changed these settings so I guess Windows 10 was setup like that.

Comment: the health assistant for installing wndows 11 works again and might tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 11 upgrade using ISO - INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE](https://superuser.com/questions/1680050/windows-11-upgrade-using-iso-inaccessible-boot-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to upgrade using USB option. Only a fresh update is available if you boot with USB.