# Windows 11 upgrade using ISO - INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

Could not get Windows 11 upgrade through Windows Update (see: [Windows 11 update check cached?](https://superuser.com/questions/1680043/windows-11-update-check-cached))

So I downloaded ISO, mounted it from drive C and ran `setup.exe` as recommended on multiple blogs.

It worked fine through to almost the end. After some time the setup wanted to reboot but could not find the boot device - failed with INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE twice and then rolled back the install..

The C drive is Gigabyte AORUS 2TB **M.2 PCIe 4.0** SSD (GP-ASM2NE6200TTTD)

BIOS:

```
Launch CSM = disabled
Secure Boot state = user
Platform Key (PK) state = unloaded
OS Type = Other OS
AMI Native NVMe Driver Support = enabled
```

How can I make it work?

[image]

Comment: There are either two explanations for the failure. [You have an known issue which is blocking the installation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-21H2). It’s not being checked as you are using an ISO.  The second is some other issue, SetupDiag, will provide more insight into the failure. We would need the output of that tool to determine the reason the upgrade failed

Comment: This just seems like a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1680047/is-there-a-way-to-upgrade-to-windows-11-using-usb) question.  In both cases you have the exact same error, multiple questions make it hard to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide the [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/windows-boot-failure) diskpart information by editing your question.

Comment: So do you still have this problem if you performed a fresh install? If your still having this problem do you have Google Driver installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the basics:

Make sure UEFI and Secure Boot are both enabled.

Make sure the computer is less than 35 months old.

Then, best (in my view) if you are not running a dual-boot system, especially with some OS that wants UEFI turned off.

Go to Git Hub and get WhyNotWin11 and run it. See what items it enumerates that will cause Windows 11 to fail.

> So I downloaded ISO, mounted it from drive C and ran setup.exe

Microsoft is checking machines before updating and it is going to take a while. You can only "force" it if everything (Windows 11 requirements) is good and correct.

You also might consider waiting some days and see if the upgrade happens normally. That is how many upgrades will happen.

Comment: I did run WhyNotWin and it shows all green.. And its single boot.

Comment: As I noted in my answer, wait several days and possibly even until November Patch Tuesday and see if the upgrade happens.

Comment: I installed a fresh copy from USB and now it is not possible to figure what was the problem. But I saw few people having the same issue on elevenforums.com