# How to install Windows 11 on Intel Mac

Tags: windows, mac, boot-camp, windows-11-upgrade

I have a MacBook Pro 4th generation (2016-2020) with Intel chip and macOS Monterey. I had Windows 10 installed via Boot Camp Assistant. I tried to install Windows 11 in the same way I had installed Windows 10, but it seems Boot Camp Assistant didn't work with Win 11. On Apple Support site I found only information about installing Windows 10 on Mac: Install Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp Assistant

How can I install original Windows 11 on Intel Mac?

Thank you in advance for assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my computer run Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1659465/will-my-computer-run-windows-11)

Comment: See https://twocanoes.com/install-windows-11-without-tpm-2-on-boot-camp/ [I haven't worked through it but if Two Canoes [makers of WinClone] say it can be done, then it can be done.

Comment: I suspect installing windows 10, running the update advisor to check for issues, then upgrading to 11 might be a solution. There's tools that disable the TPM and other checks like [this one](https://github.com/AveYo/MediaCreationTool.bat) but use at your own risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After big research I found 2 solutions which seems to be good. All details are below as-is. So, do it on your own risk. I installed Win11 on my Mac by Solution 1, cause it's more easy and has less actions.

#### Solution 1

1. [Install Windows 10](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468)
2. Use [MediaCreationTool](https://github.com/AveYo/MediaCreationTool.bat) to bypass TPM check. Please check details by the provided link.
3. Install Windows 11 for

These steps are in video format on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVIWgp1mrvg).

#### Solution 2

I haven't tried it. But it seems it's also a working solution. [Video instructions on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-61qdyppJ8)

**P.S.** Windows 10 licence key also works for Windows 11. Cheers!

Comment: Youtube videos can go down/get taken down - It might be seriously worth refactoring your answer to include essential steps to 'standalone' rather than relying on the videos to explain everything