# What will be a summary of whether the computer will be able to upgrade to Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11

Courtesy link: [Will my computer run Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1659465/will-my-computer-run-windows-11)

Prior to the actual release date, this has been the summary of whether the computer will be able to upgrade to Windows 11.

> How do I get a summary of whether my computer will be able to upgrade to Windows 11? There is a Microsoft App (PC Health Check), but I think WhyNotWin11 is more accurate:
>
> [Why Not Windows 11][8]
>
> Study the WhyNotWin11 README file, scroll down to the Download Latest Stable Release hyperlink, download and run it. You will see the dialog below:
>
> [![Why not Windows 11 screen][9]][9]
>
> You see in this screen CPU Generation. This screen came from my ThinkPad X1 laptop, and it meets all the requirements for Windows 11 except for CPU Generation.
>
> So far as I know now, the CPU must be newer than 3 years old to pass this Windows 11 test.
>
> We will not conclusively know an answer until closer to the official Windows 11 release date when clearer advice and test apps are available from Microsoft.
>
> I will typically purchase a commercial grade computer and so for me, four years is not particularly old, but apparently too old to run Windows 11.
>
> **This has been a summary to help us determine if our computers will run Windows 11.**
>
> **Follow up Note:**  I have today (June 28, 2021) installed Windows 11 Pro pre-release on my Windows Insider machine, and it is working well.

Now that it is almost 2 years following the Windows 11 release date on October 5, 2021, Microsoft must have clearer advice and test apps. Now, what will be a clearer summary of whether the computer will be able to upgrade to Windows 11?

Comment: your edits don't help, it only adds problems (needs focus - too many questions at once). [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sigh. How does help quoting an entire answer in verbatim anything, we can all read that for ourselves by clicking the link. I wish I could vote kick user.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I am definitely highlighting the difference between the linked duplicate and my question. What else are you looking for?

Comment: If you think you're being productive here: carry on. I am not looking for anything, I was asked for opinion on re-opening or not. I gave it. FWIW the whole question doesn't make any sense to me and I find it a waste of everyone's time, since you *have* 2021 requirements, so look up 2023 requirements and compare and determine differences (if any).

Comment: @JoepvanSteen By the way, Wikipedia has talk pages and discussion rooms to resolve disputes. I wish that StackExchange has something similar.

Comment: There's https://meta.superuser.com/

Comment: The answer to the duplicate absolutely still is applicable to your question and thus answers your question. In reality newer CPUs have just been added to the compatibility list.  Any CPU that isn’t listed isn’t technically compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements have not changed since Windows 11 came out. I am running Windows 11 Pro here.

CPU:  minimum 8th Generation CPU.  <-- Note this requirement.

Memory: 4 GB minimum.

TPM:  TPM V2 Minimum.

You must have UEFI installed and in use (easy requirement for a modern machine).

Secure Boot must be enabled.

If your system is older, you can sign up for the Windows Insider Program and run Windows 11 Insider. I have one Generation 7 machine running Insider.  My Desktop and Laptop are Generation 8 and 9.

Windows 11 remains a free upgrade to Windows 10 on eligible machines.

If your computer is eligible, Windows Update should initiate the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

A simple web search could have answered this question (assuming that I understand the question).

Your fist two text paragraphs of text appear to be a history lesson and not a question.  Well written but I don't see the point.  Your final question is also a bit strange.. what is the requirement on that specific machine?  The same as it is on any machine.  If you are asking if that machine is compatible, please reword the question to ask that specifically.

Yes, it is compatible as you can see on [this list](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000187485/dell-computers-tested-for-upgrade-to-windows-11) provided by Dell.

Comment: Answers that suggest a web search should have been performed, while accurate, are not necessarily helpful to the community.  Likewise, commentary about the wording of a question, while potentially accurate also is not helpful.  So, by removing (mentally), everything that potentially removing everything that isn't helpful, we are left with a link to a compatibility list by Dell which isn't cited or quoted.